# conda installed emacs suddenly not working after upgrading ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: emacs, anaconda, malloc, conda, ubuntu-22.04

I just recently upgraded to ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (from ubuntu 20.04 LTS). Before, my conda environment for emacs worked fantastically.

My conda environment I created - and retried creating using:

```
conda create --name emacs
conda activate emacs
conda install -c conda-forge emacs
emacs &
```

Output:

```
emacs: symbol lookup error: emacs: undefined symbol: malloc_get_state, version GLIBC_2.2.5
```

And emacs doesn't even start.
Does somebody know what is going on?

"Solution":

My "Solution" so far was just to install emacs globally and use it.

Comment: Tangential note, but creating environments like this (empty creation -> activate -> install packages) is error prone. One should always prefer specifying all packages at creation time when possible. I.e., `conda create -n emacs -c conda-forge emacs`

Comment: @merv Thanks for the note! Why it is error prone to install after creation?

Comment: Typos and activation issues. Using the `--name,-n` flag is more deliberate and helps avoid installing things in the wrong environment.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I see in the GLIBC 2.25

https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.25/source/NEWS

```
* The malloc_get_state and malloc_set_state functions have been removed.
  Already-existing binaries that dynamically link to these functions will
  get a hidden implementation in which malloc_get_state is a stub.  As far
  as we know, these functions are used only by GNU Emacs and this change
  will not adversely affect already-built Emacs executables.  Any undumped
  Emacs executables, which normally exist only during an Emacs build, should
  be rebuilt by re-running “./configure; make” in the Emacs build tree.
```